# Composer install in yii2 project

Tags: yii2, composer-php

I've been using yii2 for a while now but recently when cloning my project from gitlab and runing "composer install" i get these issues [image: errors]
so why?

Comment: This "Could not open input file: init" is the clue - maybe wrong read permission?

Comment: try with: $ php ./init

Comment: but it starts the installation then stops!!! Bizley